# Installed MacPorts packages sizes

Tags: macports

Can I retrieve a list of the sizes of MacPorts installed packages?

Yes, I know they are compiled from sources, but if a list of generated files is known, it should be computable anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make use of port build in command `contents`, which gives you the oportunity to do things like that:

```
port contents --size depof:python27
```

Grep the lines you need and do the maths :-)

Update: found answer [here](https://guide.macports.org/#using.port.contents) at guide.macports.

While reading a bit deeper, I found this

```
port space --units MB --total thisport
```

which is much more handy then calculating the sum of the size of each file inside a port.

Comment: I can't test it any more, so I'll just trust this to be correct.

Comment: @Lohoris : much appreciated. Added link where I found this.

Answer (score 2):

Using the command:

```
du -sh /opt/local/var/macports/software/*
```

echos back all directories and sizes of your installed ports.

Use the command:

```
port -d echo installed
```

echoes a listing of the ports installed.

Comment: Oh. I didn't know they were neatly installed in separate directories :)

Comment: Oh, they aren't. In those directories I just have the tarballs. I want to know the full current installed size.

Answer (score 2):

To get each port along with a total of all ports just type `port space installed`

Example output (partial):

```
57.425 KiB xorg-renderproto @0.11.1_0
7.189 KiB xorg-scrnsaverproto @1.2.2_0
49.408 KiB xorg-videoproto @2.3.3_0
849.766 KiB xorg-xcb-proto @1.12_1
66.130 KiB xorg-xcb-util @0.4.0_0
143.412 KiB xorg-xextproto @7.3.0_0
18.946 KiB xorg-xf86vidmodeproto @2.3.1_0
5.789 KiB xorg-xineramaproto @1.2.1_0
469.177 KiB xorg-xproto @7.0.31_0
171.815 KiB xrender @0.9.10_0
1.344 MiB XviD @1.3.4_0
1.575 MiB xz @5.2.2_0
3.102 MiB yasm @1.3.0_0
707.211 KiB zlib @1.2.8_0
3.645 GiB total
```

Comment: If you want to sort by package size use `port space --units MB installed | sort -n`.

Answer (score 1):

To list the dependencies as a hierarchy

```
psd() {
port rdeps $1 2>/dev/null | sed -E "1 s/.*of (.*) @.*/\1/" |
while IFS= read -r line
    do
        port_name="$(port space --total $line 2>/dev/null | cut -d ' ' -f 1-2)"
        port_size=${port_name% *}
        port_unit=${port_name#* }
        printf "%-30s%12.2f %s\n" "$line" "$port_size" "$port_unit"
    done
}
```

Example

```
$ psd mosh
mosh                                895.03 KiB
  pkgconfig                         629.39 KiB
    libiconv                          6.27 MiB
      gperf                           0.00 B
  ncurses                            15.17 MiB
  protobuf-cpp                       44.11 MiB
    autoconf                          0.00 B
      xz                              1.68 MiB
        gettext                      24.82 MiB
          expat                       1.11 MiB
    automake                          0.00 B
    libtool                           4.19 MiB
    zlib                            738.74 KiB
  openssl                            17.50 MiB
  p5.22-getopt-long                 132.63 KiB
    perl5.22                         54.52 MiB
      gdbm                          553.91 KiB
  p5.22-io-socket-ip                 64.05 KiB
```

Adjust the length of the formatted output, `30` in my example, as needed.
If you want the output truncated or rounded, see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/272374/format-command-output-with-variable-and-fixed-space).

To list the grand total of the above hierarchy

```
alias pst='_() { port rdeps $1 2>/dev/null | cut -d : -f 2 | xargs port space --units MiB --total $1 2>/dev/null ; } ; _'
```

Example

```
$ pst mosh
172.312 MiB total
```

You might want to check `port help space`.

I guess you could add coloring and ordering to the output.

Answer (score 0):

Well, by default they install to /opt/local so it should be as easy as cd /opt/local && du -sh * to get a list of the file sizes. Not sure if it's built into MP by default to give you overall sizes

Comment: Why not just du -sh /opt/local?

Comment: That works as well, I like being in the directory to start tinkering so go down the cd path ;)

Comment: ???. I'd like to know the *single* package size, not the sum of all the macports.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna get the size of a specific package :

```
port space [package name]
```